# VS Code intellisense appears to not be working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So I have this simple code below that I am trying to use and I wonder if I am expecting too much from intellisense in VS Code.

I installed the Trello python library using `pip3 install py-trello`.
Using VS Code (1.27.2), and Python extension (2018.8), Python (3.7.0), Mac OS (10.13.6).

In the code below, if I type board. then I do not see any intellisense help after typing the dot.
I guess it may not be clear to VS Code that board is a class type returned by client.list_boards().

```
from trello import TrelloClient

client = TrelloClient(
    api_key='my_api',
    token='my_token',
)


for board in client.list_boards():
    print(board.name)
```

I do get Intellisense popup, if I do this.

```
x = input("Name: ")
x.
```

I get a dropdown after x.

---

However, I do not get intellisense popup with this below sample code either. After I type calc. there is no intellisense popup. Copied this code from [another issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1072) on Github but I am using Python 3.7.0. I am facing the same issue, although this issue seems to have been resolved and my application versions are much higher than when the issue was raised and resolved.

```
class FactorMixin:
    Factor_1 = 1

class Calc:
    def sum(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class BetterCalc(Calc, FactorMixin):
    def multiply_factor(self,a):
        return a * self.Factor_1
    var_a=1

calc = BetterCalc()
calc.
```

calc.m shows intellisense popup, but calc. does not
[image: calc.m shows intellisense popup, but calc. does not]

And finally, here is one time when the popup does show up. Not sure what is happening and whether it is the language server starting late as some people have experienced in the past...

[image]

---

And when I set "python.jediEnabled": true in settings, the intellisense does pop up, but I wonder what I am losing out on by not using the python server...

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with or mixin example. If you are using the new language server that you give it enough time to start.

Comment: @BrettCannon Thanks for the comment! So I tried it again with the Mixin example. And out of 5 times, the intellisense popped up twice. The output console, with python selected shows - > Starting Microsoft Python language server.
Initializing for /usr/local/bin/python3
##########Linting Output - pylint##########. So the language server seems to be starting up ok. Or is it? Any other clues? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's definitely starting up okay. We should have a new version out sometime next week. After the update if this persists then please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .

Comment: Ok. Thank you @BrettCannon. Will be on the lookout and will switch off Jedi once the new version is in.